# Python : Switching between different .py files with import files

Tags: python

I'm making a car parking system and I have some problems.
So the main thing is that I have 3 different py files, and all of them have different functions. For example I use Programa.py to ask users what they would like to do and some other functions. I use GETDATA.py to get rows from PostgreSQL server and then to pay for the parking charges.
And last of all I have REGISTRATION.py to Register car numbers to parking and insert them to SQL Database.

So the main problem is that after the "What would you like to do?" menu from Programa.py I use if statement, which imports other .py files to make their job done. Here's the code of If statement in Programa.py:

```
while Pasirinkimas:
    try:
        Registration_Or_Pay = int(input("~ What would you like to do?\n1.Register a car\n2.Pay for parking\n"))
        if int(Registration_Or_Pay == 1):
            import REGISTRATION
            break
        elif int(Registration_Or_Pay == 2):
            import GETDATA
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("NOT A NUMBER!")
```

After imported GETDATA.py Let's say I paid for parking and now I have to return to Programa.py to keep the program running and performing other parking operations as number registrations again.

And the problem is that after importing the Programa.py from GETDATA.py It launches, but after picking a number, to register a number program closes.

This is some lines of GETDATA.py file which I imported from main system .py file, which is called "Programa", you can see it at the end I'm trying to import it again to always keep the program running and to return to main script which asks what you would like to do.

```
finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
        with open (Logs, mode='a',encoding='utf-8') as logwrite:
            Time = datetime.datetime.now()
            logwrite.writelines("\n {} Record SELECTED SUCCESSFULLY FROM Vartotojai DB. CARNUM {} REG_TIME: {} PARKING TIME: {} PRICE : {} STATUS : {}".format(Time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), car_numb, Laikas_ISDB, total_hours, total_charges, Time  ))
            logwrite.close()
            time.sleep(2) # 2MINUTES 2 PAY.
            os.system('cls')
            import Programa # Return to program
```

I was talking with my friend who is good at python, he mentioned that I shouldn't use imports like this, because the import runs once in runtime. only first import directive takes effect. So my question would be How should I switch between these functions?

Answer (score 0):

The last word in your question is actually what you should google for :).
Read something about functions. You put the code of the files you want to import into functions. Then you import all files you need at the beginning of your script and when you want to run the code you call the function its in.

Comment: but can I switch between them many times? Or  is there any better way to make that?

Comment: You dont "switch" between them. you import their code and run it as often as you want.